# remove timer event

Tags: actionscript-3, function, timer

I have this looping flv video and I have a random movie that is played when the movie is running. I need when i've play the other movie the `shaker` to be disabled, or to stop that random cycle. Thanks

```
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, NCListener);

function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){
if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
ns.play("video_2.flv");
shaker(null);
}
};
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,shaker);
function shaker (event:Event):void{

var mcArray:Array = [loader.button_01_mc,loader.button_02_mc,loader.button_03_mc,loader.button_04_mc,loader.button_05_mc];
var clipTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000);

clipTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playClips);

function playClips(event:TimerEvent):void{

    var i:Number=Math.floor(Math.random() * mcArray.length);
    var movieClipToEdit:MovieClip=mcArray[i] as MovieClip;
    movieClipToEdit.gotoAndPlay (1);
}
clipTimer.start();
}
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play_video_01);
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, play_effect_01);

function play_video_01 (event:MouseEvent){

    ns.play("video_3.flv");
    loader.button_01_mc.gotoAndPlay (41);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
Move the timer up and out of the function.
Call the stop in the desired function.

Update 1: Reverted the change made to the timer and added single play functionality so that only one animation plays. (does not cycle through the animations, just plays a random one.)

```
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, NCListener);

function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){
if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
ns.play("video_2.flv");
shaker(null);
}
};
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,shaker);
function shaker (event:Event):void{

var mcArray:Array =    [loader.button_01_mc,loader.button_02_mc,loader.button_03_mc,loader.button_04_mc,loader.button_05_mc];

var clipTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000);
clipTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playClips);
var refCurrentAnimation:MovieClip;

function playClips(event:TimerEvent):void{

    if(!refCurrentAnimation)
    {
        var i:Number=Math.floor(Math.random() * mcArray.length);
        var movieClipToEdit:MovieClip=mcArray[i] as MovieClip;
        movieClipToEdit.gotoAndPlay (1);
        refCurrentAnimation = movieClipToEdit;
        clipTimer.stop();
    }
}
clipTimer.start();
}
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play_video_01);
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, play_effect_01);

function play_video_01 (event:MouseEvent){

    ns.play("video_3.flv");
    loader.button_01_mc.gotoAndPlay (41);
}
```

Comment: It's working like that. But when i play video_3.flv and wait for it's end to start video_2.flv. And by time video_2.flv is playing there are 2 random movie clips playing from `mcArray`. After another cycle there are 3 movie clips played ?

Comment: and you want those to stop? or only a single one to play? to get it to stop all you to do is: put clipTimer.stop(); before the ns.play("video_2.flv"); inside the same function. to get only a single one to play: you want to create a var refCurrent:MovieClip outside of the playClips function and inside check to see if the refCurrent.currentFrame==refCurrent.totalFrames before telling a new movieClipToEdit to play and dont forget to store movieClipToEdit in the refCurrent declaration.

Comment: i need  only a single one to play. Could you give it as a code please. Thank you.